# In my custom UIView, setting a subview's backgroundColor causes it to cover up my drawRect drawings (CGContextRef, CGMutablePathRef,etc). How to fix?

Tags: ios, uiview, drawrect

I have a custom container view with an orange `backgroundColor`.

In this custom view I draw lines by overriding `drawRect`. This works great until I try and draw lines over subviews.

Here are some screenshots that correlate with code edits to illustrate the issue I'm facing:

[image]
^ This image shows my custom view with `self.graphBackgroundView` present, but without an explicit `backgroundColor` being set. My line from my `drawRect` is visible. This is good.

[image]
^ This image shows my custom view with `self.graphBackgroundView` present, but WITH an explicit `backgroundColor` being set. It's as if my green subview's z-index is higher than my drawRect's z-index, or something.

[image]
^ Finally, this image shows my custom view with `self.graphBackgroundView` present, an explicit `backgroundColor` being set (still green), but WITH the `self.graphBackgroundView.layer.opacity` set to 0.25. Here we can see the drawRect line again but it's not quite right, we really wish the line would draw on top of the view entirely, not underneath.

The real issue is what we see in the green screenshot. We want the opaque green subview, we just want our white line to draw on top of it.

Any help much appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // GET CONTEXT
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // INIT PATH
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    // CONFIG PATH
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(context, CGColorGetComponents([UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor)); // 4 color component white for use with CGColorGetComponents

    // ESTABLISH STARTING POINT
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0.0, 100.0);

    // GRAPH NEXT POINT
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, 120.0, 160.0, 120.0, 160.0);

    // GRAPH NEXT POINT
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, 130.0, 170.0, 130.0, 170.0);

    // ADD THE PATH
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);

    // DRAW
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        // INIT UI ELEMENTS
        self.graphBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];

        // INIT AUTO LAYOUT VIEWS DICT
        self.viewsDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        [self.viewsDictionary setObject:self.graphBackgroundView forKey:@"graphBackgroundView"];

        // TURN ON AUTO LAYOUT
        self.graphBackgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        // ESTABLISH VIEW HIERARCHY
        [self addSubview:self.graphBackgroundView];

        // LAYOUT

        // graphBackgroundView
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(0)-[graphBackgroundView]-(0)-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:self.viewsDictionary]];
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(topMargin)-[graphBackgroundView]-(bottomMargin)-|" options:0 metrics:@{@"topMargin":self.topMargin,@"bottomMargin":self.bottomMargin} views:self.viewsDictionary]];

        // CONFIG

        // self
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor]; // My drawRect code DOES draw on top of this color

        // graphBackgroundView
        self.graphBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; // My drawRect code does NOT draw on top of this color
        //self.graphBackgroundView.layer.opacity = 0.25; // <-- If I uncomment this I can kind of see the line I'm drawing underneath it via the effects of transparency
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's as if my green subview's z-index is higher than my drawRect's z-index, or something.

Well, that's exactly the case. If you have a superview and its subviews, the subviews are drawn *in front of* the superview. That is part of what it means to be a subview. The only surprise here is that you're surprised.

Comment: At the time I was writing the code I was thinking of the containing custom view as a "single thing". Like, `drawRect` took care of drawing itself and its subviews (in my `init` I'm laying them out...). Yes I see now how that doesn't make any sense when you think of views, their internal drawing code, etc... At any rate, I've got it figured out now and your answer is hilarious. It's very helpful in the sense that it clarifies exactly what's going on here. Cheers mate, thanks!